# Why is FindMinimum slow for this convex cost function of one variable?

Tags: performance-tuning, mathematical-optimization

I implemented a Kalman filter, which perfectly works. This filter has four parameters denoted here by `Q1,Q2,R1,R2`. I'd like to find the optimal parameters, in the sense of an error measured by a function `error`. To make it simple, I fix `Q2,R1,R2` and the optimization problem is only in *one* variable, `Q1`.

**My problem in short** The cost function to optimize is quite unexpensive to compute and is (at least locally) convex:

```
ListLinePlot[Table[{Q1,error[Q1,0.01,0.1,0.1]},{Q1,0,1,0.01}]] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

However, when trying to optimize:

```
FindMinimum[{error[Q1, 0.01, 0.1, 0.1], 0 <= Q1 <= 1.}, {Q1, 0.1}]
```

never seems to end.

My goal would be to be able to optimize for all four parameters, but I fail even for one. It's not clear to me since the cost function seem to be nice. Any ideas on why `FindMinimum` is slow?

**Full code**:

```
(* generate data (vList) from reference (vFun) *)
n=200;
SeedRandom[1234]
vData=RandomReal[{-1,1},2*n];
vFun[t_]=Fit[vData,Table[t^n,{n,0,50}],t];
vList=Array[vFun,n,{0,n}]+.2*RandomReal[{-.3,.3},n];
aList=Array[vFun',n,{0,n}]+.2*RandomReal[{-.05,.05},n];

(* definitions *)
A={{1.,1},{0,1}};
y=Transpose[{vList,aList}];
x[0]={0,0};
p[0]=DiagonalMatrix[{10,10.}]; 

(* process iteration i *)
step[i_]:=Block[{},
  pttm1[i]=A.p[i-1].Transpose[A]+Q;
  Kt[i]=pttm1[i].Inverse[(pttm1[i]+R)];
  x[i]=A.x[i-1]+Kt[i].(y[[i]]-A.x[i-1]);
  p[i]=(IdentityMatrix[2]-Kt[i]).pttm1[i];]

(* run n steps *)
run[Q1_,Q2_,R1_,R2_]:=Block[{},
  Q=DiagonalMatrix[{Q1,Q2}]; 
  R=DiagonalMatrix[{R1,R2}];
  Array[step,n];
  Array[x[#][[1]]&,n]]

(* cost function *)
error[Q1_, Q2_, R1_, R2_] := Block[{xKal},
  xKal = run[Q1, Q2, R1, R2];
  Total@Table[(vFun[i] - xKal[[i]])^2, {i, 1, Length[xKal]}]]
```

Just for information, the aim of the Kalman filter is to denoise a signal. Example:

```
sol = run[0.0001, 0.01, 0.3, 0.1];
Show[Plot[vFun[t], {t, 1, n}, PlotStyle -> Red], 
 ListLinePlot[{vList, sol}, PlotRange -> Full, DataRange -> {0, n}]]
```

The red curve is the objective, the blue curve is the input data, the orange curve is the filtered data. The parameters are not optimal here, i.e. with some better parameters the orange curve would better match the red one.
[image]

Comment: You have `0 <= Q1 < 0` inside the `FindMinimum` call... Is that intentional?

Comment: @Rahul Thank you for pointing out, that's a typo. The problem still holds.

Comment: Maybe you should consider the command `KalmanFilter`?

Comment: @bills My goal is to really understand what happens in a Kalman filter, so I prefer to write it with my own hands. It proves to be also a good way of learning MMA :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem seems to be that time is spent evaluating `error` symbolically.  If I define

```
fn[q_?NumericQ] := error[q, 0.01, 0.1, 0.1]
```

then

```
FindMinimum[{fn[Q1], 0 <= Q1 <= 1.}, {Q1, 0.1}]
```

evaluates quickly, giving

```
{0.566953, {Q1 -> 0.0883772}}
```

Comment: Seems to solve the problem. How did you find this? I thought MMA would treat everything as numeric, since all the variables have numeric values.

Comment: I think that MMA tries to understand the symbolic form of the expression it is being asked to minimise, before attempting minimisation.  In your case, evaluating `error[Q1, 0.01, 0.1, 0.1]` takes a long time (presumably your code is not intended to work with symbolic inputs).  The technique of adding `?NumericQ` to any input that only makes sense when defined as an explicit number is a very general one, and is a good "defensive" coding technique.